# Replacing numbers in a row with another number from another column if the numbers are lower than 1000

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft, if

I need to substitute numbers in a row if they are lower than 1000 with the mean of numbers in that row calculated without inclusion of the numbers in the row that are lower than 1000.

I've successfully calculated the mean using this code `=AVERAGE(IF(O3:V3>=1000, O3:V3))`, however, when I try to substitute the numbers that are lower than 1000 with the calculated mean, I receive `#spill error`. This is the code I'm using: `=IF(O3:V3<1000, W3, O3:V3)`. Mean values are located in column "W".

Comment: Please explain more "substitute the numbers that are lower than 1000 with the calculated mean".

Comment: Let's say these are the numbers in my row: 

1250 1600 840  

I want to replace 840 (since it is below 1000), with the mean of 1250 and 1600 (1425) and then calculate the new mean. The updated row should look like this:

1250 1600 1425

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate this with a formula like this:

```
=IF(O3:V3>=1000,O3:V3,AVERAGEIF(O3:V3,">=1000"))
```

but the result will be in another row.
If you want the result be in the same place you should use vba.
[image: Average]
If you want to replace actual values with a calculated average you should select your data and run this code:

```
Sub UpdateSmallValues()
   Dim avg As Double, res As Range
   ' operate on a selected range
   avg = WorksheetFunction.AverageIf(Selection, ">=1000")
   For Each res In Selection
      If res.Value < 1000 Then res.Value = avg
   Next res
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The code you wrote calculates the new mean which is great, but I also want to update the cells that were below 1000, with the mean of other cells that were not below 1000.